# Canonical link redirect not working

Tags: redirect, google-analytics

I have added a canonical link to redirect from www to non-www version instead of working in the htaccess file but when I type www.example.com it does not redirect to example.com.

In google webmaster tools I have set the preferred domain as non-www and in google analytics the website domain is also non-www.

Any ideas what I am missing?

Comment: Can you post your `.htaccess`?

Comment: I can but that is a secondary......I have been told to 1st do the redirect using canonical link. This has been applied to a project before and is working fine but unfortunately it is not working now....dont know what I am missing.